# Common Lisp auto completion in emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, common-lisp, slime

### Update

Apparently, the `auto-complete` package is not the culprit. 
**Emacs fails to download melpa archive.**

A quick google search indicates that this is a reappearing problem both on windows and unix machines.

As there are already threads concerning **failed to download 'melpa' archive** (none of which helped unfortunately) this thread may or may not be closed.

### Inital Question

I'm trying to set up emacs for Common Lisp.
I installed sbcl and the slime package.

Some time ago I used to have auto completion for Common Lisp keywords in emacs such that - while typing - it suggested a word via a greyed out completion (TAB for acceptance) or via drop down or both. (I can't remember exactly.)

I'm struggling to get this working again.

At https://github.com/purcell/ac-slime it is suggested to first install auto-complete but when I type `package-list-packages` there is no such package. (But there are plenty named `auto-complete-*`).

(I set up Melpa with:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
    '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

The provided link http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/ is dead as well.
`M-x` `install-package` [RET] `auto-complete` [RET] also fails. Emacs says: `[No match]`

So my question is:
If there is no `auto-complete` package anymore, what is a good way to set up Common Lisp auto completion in emacs in the way mentioned above (greyed out word or dropdown)?

Comment: FYI [Portacle](https://shinmera.github.io/portacle/) is a multiplatform and portable customized Emacs (with autocomplete) + SBCL + Quicklisp + Git.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I might give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The current home-page for auto-complete is https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete

Installing it should be enough to allow you to use ac-slime (there is also a completion version using company).

Comment: On the site you suggested it says: "You can install auto-complete with the following command.`M-x package-install [RET] auto-complete [RET]`" but when I type this emacs says `[No match]`

Comment: @Frank that is available if you have melpa setup. Although the readme seems to assume the readere to be familiar with what melpa is.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have MELPA set up and the package is not found with the name `auto-complete.` However, if you manually search for it after `package-list-packages`, you can see it. The name has some dates after `auto-complete.` I have not gotten it to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work.

1. Download the .ZIP archive with repository [here](https://github.com/auto-complete).
2. Unzip
3. Run `M-x package-install-file`
4. On the prompt, specify the path to the downloaded repository and the file named `auto-complete.el`.
5. Make sure that installation returns something along the lines of "Successful"
6. Add this line to your Emacs initialization file (`.emacs`):
   `(ac-config-default)`
7. To auto-complete in SLIME, follow similar step to install `ac-slime` (requires SLIME and Auto-complete)

P.S. There is another package called `company` (stands for Complete Anything), which is quite good as an alternative. I am trying it out now. Getting it to work was very simple.